# AS3 Help a noob with some debugging?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

I haven't really learned a whole lot about debugging with a console yet, but when I run the Flash debugger i get the following error:

```
Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL     
C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Shortcuts\Project Folder\FLA FILES\bug free version.swf [SWF] 
C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Shortcuts\Project Folder\FLA FILES\bug free version.swf - 16186539 bytes after decompression
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property TIMER not found on flash.events.TimerEvent and there is no default value.
at bugfreeversion_fla::MainTimeline/completeFunction()[bugfreeversion_fla.MainTimeline::frame243:19]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I'm not really sure how to extract the information I need from this, all I can figure is there is a data problem with my countdown timer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to access a property called "TIMER" on your TimerEvent instance when your TimerEvent instance does not have a "TIMER" property. The error is happening in your `completeFunction()`

`Property TIMER not found on flash.events.TimerEvent`

```
at bugfreeversion_fla::MainTimeline/completeFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction() 
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent() at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: Seems pretty solid, but right now I'm using a completeTimer function, and it's using parameters : completeTimer(e:TimerEvent); is this an incorrect use of the parameters?

Comment: Do you have a function in your timeline called "completeFunction" ?

Comment: Yeah, here's the code: myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,completeFunction);
function completeFunction(e:TimerEvent) Obviously it just ends the timer
{
 SoundMixer.stopAll();
 gotoAndStop(245, "Scene 1");
 myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
 myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,completeFunction);
 }

Comment: The code you posted here looks fine to me. For some reason the compiler is saying TimerEvent.TIMER is invalid.  Can you try importing: flash.utils.Timer and flash.events.TimerEvent?

Comment: Yeah, I did that back when I first started the project. I only imported on frame 1 through, and this code is on 230-something of the same scene, do I need to re-import that code?

Comment: it looks like this line `myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);` should in fact be this? `myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, countdown);`

Comment: Holy crap, I'm stupid. Thank you so much, will comment again if this was the fix.